# Django Zoho SMTPAuthenticationError (535, b'Authentication Failed')

Tags: django, smtp, djoser

I'm using Django's email backend to send account verification emails. This is what my setup looks like:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.in'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'someone@example.com'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'someone@example.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'somepassword'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

This configuration worked fine for till a few hours ago when it suddenly stopped working, throwing this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 125, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 19, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djoser/views.py", line 144, in perform_create
    settings.EMAIL.activation(self.request, context).send(to)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/templated_mail/mail.py", line 78, in send
    super(BaseEmailMessage, self).send(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py", line 284, in send
    return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 102, in send_messages
    new_conn_created = self.open()
  File "/home/ubuntu/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 69, in open
    self.connection.login(self.username, self.password)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 734, in login
    raise last_exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 723, in login
    (code, resp) = self.auth(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/smtplib.py", line 646, in auth
    raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'Authentication Failed')
```

I'm not sure what triggered the error but now it doesn't work with other host accounts as well. I haven't changed anything, and my Zoho account's 2FA has not been activated either. What could've been the reason for it to stop working?

Answer (score -2):

just changed this line

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.in'
```

to this line

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.zoho.com'
```

I still this not solve your problem than it means you have turned on two factor authentication in your zoho account. So please turn it off or just generate application generated password in zoho account and use it in your code.

Comment: None of them worked, I presume it was an error with Zoho's servers, because it worked the next day without a change.

Comment: ok good but in general, this will solve the problem because I faced the same problem and solved it by using this tricks.

Comment: Changing it to `smtp.zoho.com` wouldn't always help, that seems to depend on where one is registered. If you're registered in the Indian zoho domain, `then smtp.zoho.com` might not help.

Comment: This worked for me and I'm registered in the UK. The Zoho docs told me to use smtp.zoho.eu but this gave the same error as above.